# How to send a transactional email manually?

Tags: magento-1, email, transactional-mail

I have created an email with a coupon for customers. It is now in the list of the transactional email in the admin as a new layout.

Is there a way to send that transactional email manually to those customers I would like to send?

Or do transactional emails need to be sent only in a programmatic way or with an extension?

Comment: Afaik there is no way to send a transactionnal email manually (besides the one on the order). I think you need to develop a little something in a controller so as to be able to send the email. Perhaps a mailing extension can help you with that.

Comment: Developing a controller will I be able to select to which customer to send that email?

Comment: If you can have a multiselect somewhere, or run a query returning a list of customer emails, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Loads the html file named 'custom_email_template1.html' from

**app/locale/en_US/template/email/activecodeline_custom_email1.html**

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                        ->loadDefault('custom_email_template1');                                    

//Create an array of variables to assign to template
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'] = 'Branko';
$emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'] = 'Ajzele';
$emailTemplateVariables['myvar3'] = 'ActiveCodeline';

/**
 * The best part 
 * Opens the activecodeline_custom_email1.html, throws in the variable array
 * and returns the 'parsed' content that you can use as body of email
 */
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

/*
 * Or you can send the email directly,
 * note getProcessedTemplate is called inside send()
 */
$emailTemplate->send('john@someemail.com','John Doe', $emailTemplateVariables);
```

you need to add an entry to your `config.xml`

```
...

    <label>ActiveCodeline custom email module</label>
                    activecodeline_custom_email1.html
                    html

...
```

**app/locale/en_US/template/email/activecodeline_custom_email1.html**

```
<!--@subject ActiveCodeline custom email module @-->

Hi there {{var myvar1}} {{var myvar2}} from {{var myvar3}}. This is just some example template to test custom email module...
```

Source : http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/

Comment: Do I create in this way an html email (activecodeline_custom_email1.html) to be sent to john@someemail.com?

Comment: Yes, look the source link